# How to get values of left/right/top/bottom properties in pixel using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I need to get the left/right/top/bottom property of the `#test` in `px`. My js code giving the property value as `auto`. How to get the value in `px`?

```
<div id="test">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
</div>
```

```css
#test{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    var left = window.getComputedStyle(test).getPropertyValue("left");
    console.log(left);  // auto
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  
  var left = test.offsetLeft;
  var right = test.offsetWidth - left;
  var top = test.offsetTop;
  var bottom = test.offsetHeight - top;
  
  document.write("Left:" + left + "//"); 
  document.write("Right:" + right + "//"); 
  document.write("Top:" + top + "//");
  document.write("Bottom:" + bottom);
};
```

```css
#test{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `offsetLeft` instead

`test.offsetLeft`

```js
window.onload = function(){

    var test = document.getElementById("test");

    document.write(test.offsetLeft);  // auto
};
```

```css
#test{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <p>Dummy text</p>
</div>
```